# Is it a general statement when talking about "animals" without explicitly using generalising words?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

This [post](https://www.crownacademyenglish.com/besides-except-apart-from/) gives an excellent explanation about the difference among “besides”, “except” and “apart from”. Although some other website visitors and I can’t understand clearly the different between *except* and *except for.*

> We only use “except for” in statements which are NOT general statements (rule_1) and do NOT come after generalising words. (rule_2)

that post marks this sentence as right

> I like animals except for hamsters (YES)

and marks this one as wrong

> I like animals except hamsters (NO)

obviously, these examples applies rule_2, since there is no generalising words at all.

## question

What about rule_1, is "animals" part a general statement?

Comment: You've found a website owned by a guy with no credentials except that he claims to be a teacher of English as a second language. I've never heard of his rule, and neither have many people who are cataloged in the Corpus of Contemporary American English.